# use of mvc in project

Tags: java

i am a student(8th semester I.T.).i want to know the use of MVC(model view controller)in project...please explain..thanks

Comment: Don't you think your question is a bit overly broad?  Wouldn't it be more help for you to read a tutorial or two and then ask a *specific* question or questions about points you don't understand?

Comment: not really.we have this topic in our syllabus

Comment: What does that mean and how does it relate to my concern that your question is overly broad and fails to demonstrate any initial effort on your part?

Answer (score 2):

[MVC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) is an architectural pattern which can be used to organize the logic within an application.  Unsurprisingly, it separates the logic into Models (business logic, the bulk of the knowledge in the code), Views (UI display and logic) and Controllers (sort of an eventing model for the UI to interact with the business logic).

This is by no means the only pattern one can use.  But it's a commonly used one and fairly simple to understand.  Whether or not to use it is an architectural decision on a case-by-case (or project-by-project) basis.

Comment: thank u very much david...what i want to know is use of mvc in real life projects

Comment: @garima: The MVC pattern is used in real life projects, yes.  (As opposed to theoretical projects?)  It's not clear what you're asking, really.  Can you be more specific?

Answer (score 1):

this should get you started:
[Java SE Application Design With MVC](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/index-142890.html)

Answer (score 0):

MVC(Model | View | Controller) is a compound design pattern made of several design patterns. If you need to learn this pattern easily learn about the Observer pattern and Strategy pattern which MVC is made of. Models and Views use Observer pattern, there views are observers of models. When ever there is a change in the view, view trigger the controller to update the model. Then controller updates the model and then as View is the observer of the model model updates the view.